# Do jquery delay and queue:false negate each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, delay

This is my code:

```
$('.content').delay(1000).animate({left: '10'}, {duration:1000, queue:false});
$('.content').delay(1000).animate({opacity: 0}, {duration:1000, queue:false});
```

Content div is supposed to move left 10px and fade out simultaneously, and it does just fine. Doesn't do the 1000 delay though. Does the queue:false negate the delay?

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/animate/, _queue: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately._

Comment: have you tried it with queue:true?

Comment: @Huangism queue:true does the same as not having the queue attribute at all. Everything animates in a linear way, with the delays and animations proceeding in a queue.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify for an animation to not queue, the delay will be ignored because the delay is a callback added to the queue that the animation is ignoring.

Update:

```
$('.content').delay(1000).animate({left: 10,opacity: 0}, {duration:1000});
```

Comment: Do you know how I would get them to animate at the same time after a specified delay?

Comment: Yes, apply them both within the same `.animate` method. updating.

Comment: How would the syntax be? This is what I'm typing and it's not working :/  
$('.content').delay(1000).animate({left: '10'}, {opacity: 0}, {duration:1000});